# Inverse circular buffer

Tags: arrays, algorithm, iterator, buffer

i'm not really into basics algorithm programming, so here's my problem. I want to create an algorithm which can populate a circular buffer but it have to start at the end of the buffer. I am trying to do it since many hours without succes, so i ask for your help.

I know the original algorithm which start by the begining of the buffer :
    i = (i+1)%buffLen

But i want something that put something from buffLen-1 to 0, and when it reach 0, it start over from buffLen-1.

I know it can be done with a condition, but i'm sure there is a formula to do it faster and cleaner.

I need it to iterate infinitly through an array of objects by the end.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Faster? I doubt you would notice any difference at all. Cleaner? I'm almost sure a cryptic magical formula is going to be harder to read than a trivial `if (i == (bufLen - 1)) i = 0`. what is the problem with this? (by the way, you are the perfect example of how cryptic would be such a "formula": you said that you know how to do it with an `if`, but you are unable to find an equivalent expression with modular arithmetics by yourself...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
i = (i + buffLen - 1) % buffLen;
```

It isn't going to be any more efficient than (or even as efficient as) an `if..else` construct, but it's the analog to the one-line assignment for moving in the positive direction.

Comment: For many programming languages `i = (i-1) % buffLen` may also work, but Ted's solution is safer.

Comment: @Cito - According to this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), it will work in very few languages. It doesn't work in Java, JavaScript, C/C++, or C#.

Comment: Ok, probably I should s/many/some, but at least it works in Perl, Python and Ruby.